# Jenkins doesn't see branches from git

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am running a jenkins pipeline, which is fetching git repo like this:

```
stage('Stash sources') {
    steps {
        script {
            stash name: 'repo_source'
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Then I want to compare to branches like this:

```
git diff --name-only -r ${env.CHANGE_BRANCH} ${env.CHANGE_TARGET} | xargs -L1 dirname | uniq | awk '{print "./"\$0}'
```

But, Jenkins doesn't have the branches now, getting this output:

[image]

Comment: From the logs you provided it seems the posted Jenkinsfile ("Code") is incomplete, please include your `checkout` step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Jenkins setup, according to the censored image you showed (by the way, don't use images where cut and paste text will serve), "clones" the repository by:

- creating an empty repository (one with no commits and no branches: `git init <path>`)
- adding a remote (`git config remote.origin.url <url>`, `git config remote.origin.fetch <refspec>`)
- running `git fetch ... -- <url> <refspec>`

This process is a little bit silly as it could be done with `git clone` and/or without repeating the URL and/or refspec.

The *`refspec`* that your Jenkins code uses is:

```
+refs/heads/PRCI:refs/remotes/origin/PR-262
```

This refspec means that your Git copies only the commits reachable from the `origin` Git repository's `PRCI` branch; those commits are, in your repository, on *no* branch, but are found by the name `origin/PR-262`.

Your Jenkins code then runs `git checkout 1b6c2cf8af034bb41661dce739d9a0058<something-obscured>`.  Presumably this is a full raw hash ID.  This creates no new branches, so your repository continues to have no branches at all; `HEAD` is now detached at the specified commit.

Jenkins itself is pretty horrible and I'm no Jenkins expert, but this is clearly not what you want it to do.  You'll need to reconfigure it, or use a different plug-in, or something, or write a Jenkinsfile so that you control everything much more directly.  Have your Jenkins run `git clone` properly and/or have it copy or create all the branches you want using a proper refspec.  A simple (though slightly expensive) way would be to make a full clone and copy *all* branches:

```
git fetch origin '+refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*'
```

or you could use the `refs/remotes/origin/` names in your `git diff`.  That is, instead of:

```
git diff --name-only -r ${env.CHANGE_BRANCH} ${env.CHANGE_TARGET} | ...
```

you could use:

```
git diff --name-only -r origin/${env.CHANGE_BRANCH} origin/${env.CHANGE_TARGET} | ...
```

(but you'd still need a full clone, not one that changes branch `PRCI` into remote-tracking-name `PR-262`).

There is probably something else going on here that explains the reason for the weird refspec passed to `git fetch`, and it would be worth figuring out what that is.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have both branches checked out into your local workspace? If your `CHANGE_TARGET` branch is in a remote and not checked out locally, then git cannot find the branch to do the diff. The error states that the branch is not available in your working tree, and this refers to your local file system. So do the checkout first, and then you should have no trouble performing the diff.